# Dynamically generated input fields - how to access value

Tags: reactjs, forms, input, onclick, ref

I am developing a spa in reactjs.

One of my components maps over an array, and generates subcomponents which contain input boxes, that look like this:

```
  <div>
       <textarea placeholder="Please add a response here." id={review._id} 
                        type="text" className={style.responseBox}/><br/>
       <button  onClick={this.submitResponse} className= 
                       {style.responseButton}>Submit your response</button>
 </div>
```

How do I get the "submitResponse" event handler to access the value of the field id={review._id}?

I would like something like this:

(where 'id' is the id of the input element)

```
submitResponse(event, id){
console.log('user submitted value at input field id", id);
console.log('the value entered by the user at that field is', this.event.id.target.value);
}
```

Since the component dynamically generates these input fields, I cannot declare them ahead of time in the state, otherwise I would make these controlled input fields.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this.

```
        <button
            onClick={(event) => {
                this.submitResponse(event, review._id);
            }}
            className={style.responseButton}
        >
            Submit your response
        </button>
```

Comment: Thank you. That does give me access to the id, but does not give me access to the value of the input element.